# How to have a function call itself only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code keeps repeating, but i want it to happen twice, after the functions call and then after the set period of time using `setTimeout`.

```
function alertit() {
     alert('code');
     setTimeout(alertit, 200);
}

alertit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply condition logic over here.

```
    var callfunc = true;
    function alertit() {
         alert('code');
      if(callfunc == true)
         setTimeout(function(){ callfunc = false; alertit();}, 200);
    }

    alertit();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function alertit(callAgain) {
     alert('code');
     if (callAgain) setTimeout("alertit(false)", 200);
}

alertit(true);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. You need to pass a function to setTimeout and you are passing undefined (the result of alertit)

Comment: @Kaizo Now it works, quotes around function call were missing.

Answer (score 2):

```
function alertit() {
     alert('code');
}

alertit();
setTimeout(alertit, 200);
```

for example.

Comment: Less compact but more intuitive than the other one.

Comment: It isn't less compact. It has the same number of lines! One was just moved from inside to outside the function.

Comment: The function needs to call itself or else the rest of my code breaks. Timeout has to be inside.

Comment: this is the best way to refactor your original code. if the function needs to call itself then please rephrase the question.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this

```
function alertit(){

    // guard code
    if ( alertit.times == 2 ) return ; // for 4 times, alertit.times == 4  
    alertit.times = alertit.times ?  ++alertit.times: 1;

    // your function logic goes here ..   
    alert( 'here function called ' + alertit.times  );

    setTimeout( alertit , 1000 );
}

alertit();
```

Answer (score 1):

if the call to `setTimeout` has to be inside:

```
function alertit() {
  var f = function () {
    alert('code');
  }
  f();
  setTimeout(f, 200);
}

alertit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two flags to achieve. count will make sure your method runs for two times and the execute flag makes sure only first time the timeout is set.

```
var execute = true;
var count = 0;

function alertit() {
    if (count < 2) {
        alert('code');
        if (execute) {
            setTimeout(alertit, 200);
            execute = false;
        }
    }

}

alertit();
```

I see I have given a similar answer like tangelo which is doing the same in simple, easy steps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a more general approach, you could set up something like this:

```
function callMultipleTimes(func, count, delay) {
    var key = setInterval(function(){
        if (--count <= 0) {
            clearInterval(key);
        }
        func();
    }, delay);
}

function alertit() {
     alert('code');
}

callMultipleTimes(alertit, 2, 200);
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fyf9x/)**

Answer (score 0):

Create a Global variable call It  _Count = 0
and in the function alertit() do an if  condition if ( _Count <> 1 ) call the function and then if this codition is true Increment your variable and call the function ...